# how to autodetect the user agent in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, user-agent

I have a minor issue getting my user agent detection to work. Whenever i try it on production it does not work.. i have this in my application controller

```
before_filter :prepare_for_mobile

private

def mobile_device?
  if session[:mobile_param]
    session[:mobile_param] == "1"
  else
    request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
  end
end
helper_method :mobile_device?

def prepare_for_mobile
  session[:mobile_param] = params[:mobile] if params[:mobile]
  request.format = :mobile if mobile_device?
end
```

but it does not work when i am on production mode.. so also i would like to know how to set the user agent for blackberry andriod, iphone, nokias3, bada and windows os. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you post a copy of your config/environments/production.rb file?

Side-Note:
You probably want to add something like this if you don't want to break xml or json output, (with responds_to blocks):

```
def prepare_for_mobile
  if request.format == 'text/html'
    session[:mobile_param] = params[:mobile] if params[:mobile]
    request.format = :mobile if mobile_device?
  end
end
```